# '@' creating a comment box that allows me to tag

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, comments, tagging

I am creating a small blog-like website, and i would like to integrate the option to tag other users on comments or post using the `@` symbol like facebook or twitter does. I have searched throughout the website and haven't found anything similar nor do i know what this is called.

My question is, what programming language would i need to do this? taking in count that you can press the `@` symbol anywhere in the comment box, a list of your friends will pop up. i am making my website using PHP and MySQL. I would like to know any tips, tutorials or advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a "@" functionality for your website will have to use ajax, PHP,and MySQL. Where ajax makes a call to a PHP file that pulls up and searches through the user's friend list and displays what friend the person is looking for. Also, you will have to make sure that as the user types that friend list keeps is constantly searched and shortened so the user can easily find the person they are looking for.